# Disabling the target="_blank" on admin site title link

Tags: control-panel, admin

I'm looking to hook into this somehow to adjust the title home page link in the top left corner of the admin pages to stop opening in a new tab. Anyone have any good solutions for removing the `target="_blank"`?

Here's a sample of the code in question:

```
<div class="topbar">
    <a class="site-name" href="http://sitename.com/" title="Site Homepage" target="_blank">
        <h2>Site Name</h2>
     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the handy [Control Panel JS plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) and add some JS that targets the `site-name` class on the anchor and removes it.  jQuery's [removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) should do the trick.